# Maven enforcer plugin not matching regex on parent version

Tags: maven-3, maven-enforcer-plugin

I am pretty stumped by a rule failure match in the enforcer plugin. The regex validates the *revision* property, but when the same regex is applied to **project.parent.version**(commented out in the pom shown) it fails:

```
Image must not have a SNAPSHOT parent 18:
```

My maven version is 3.3.9, here is my full pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>appimage-test</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<groupId>test</groupId>
<version>2.0.0</version>

<properties>
    <revision>18</revision>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>mygrp</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact_id</artifactId>
    <version>18</version>
</parent>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-image-revision-property</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <!-- 
                                <requireProperty>
                                   <property>project.parent.version</property>
                                   <regex>\d\d</regex>
                                   <regexMessage>Image must not have a SNAPSHOT parent ${project.parent.version}:</regexMessage>
                                 </requireProperty>
                                 -->
                                 <requireProperty>
                                     <property>revision</property>
                                     <regex>\d\d</regex>
                                     <regexMessage>Regex did not match:${revision}:</regexMessage>                    
                                 </requireProperty>
                             </rules>
                         </configuration>
                     </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Changing the expression for **project.parent.version** to \d+.* makes it pass yet \d\d.* and \d+ do not...(if you're wondering why I don't use what works, I need to validate a more complicated regex so I'm trying to understand what I'm missing here)

Per comment request here is a debug log output:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@46c9220]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) fail = true
[DEBUG]   (s) failFast = false
[DEBUG]   (f) ignoreCache = false
[DEBUG]   (f) mojoExecution = org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce {execution: enforce-image-revision-property}
[DEBUG]   (s) project = MavenProject: test:appimage-test:2.0.0 @ /home/myuser/myproject/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) property = project.parent.version
[DEBUG]   (s) regex = \d+
[DEBUG]   (s) regexMessage = Image must not have a SNAPSHOT parent 18:
[DEBUG]   (s) property = revision
[DEBUG]   (s) regex = \d\d
[DEBUG]   (s) regexMessage = Regex did not match:18:
[DEBUG]   (s) rules = [org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireProperty@4c500a2, org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireProperty@21ac8e20]
[DEBUG]   (s) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@47a6e825
[DEBUG]   (s) skip = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Executing rule: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireProperty
[DEBUG] Adding failure due to exception
org.apache.maven.enforcer.rule.api.EnforcerRuleException: Image must not have a SNAPSHOT parent 18:
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.AbstractPropertyEnforcerRule.execute(AbstractPropertyEnforcerRule.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.EnforceMojo.execute(EnforceMojo.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[DEBUG] Executing rule: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireProperty
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireProperty failed with message:
Image must not have a SNAPSHOT parent 18:
```

I am hesitant to publish the full debug log as it's hard for me to scrub it properly, but here is the plugin versioning information:

```
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=137, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=49, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=8, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=112, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=150, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=10}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:jar:1.4.1:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]          org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.22:compile
[DEBUG]    commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.enforcer:enforcer-api:jar:1.4.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.enforcer:enforcer-rules:jar:1.4.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.shared:maven-common-artifact-filters:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.shared:maven-dependency-tree:jar:2.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:0.9.0.M2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.plugin-testing:maven-plugin-testing-harness:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]       junit:junit:jar:4.11:compile
[DEBUG]          org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < project>test:appimage-test:2.0.0
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:jar:1.4.1
[DEBUG]   Included: backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.22
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.enforcer:enforcer-api:jar:1.4.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.enforcer:enforcer-rules:jar:1.4.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-common-artifact-filters:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-dependency-tree:jar:2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:0.9.0.M2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugin-testing:maven-plugin-testing-harness:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.0.4
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:4.11
[DEBUG]   Included: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@46c9220]
```

Comment: Using the regex `\d\d` , `\d\d.*`, `\d+` works fine for me when the parent version is `18`. Can you share the complete logs for the problem you're facing to verify the plugin versions that are being at your end.

Comment: @nullpointer, I added some logs, the post is very long now, but basically this does not pass for me: <requireProperty>
                                   <property>project.parent.version</property>
                                   <regex>\d\d</regex>
                                   <regexMessage>Image must not have a SNAPSHOT parent ${project.parent.version}:</regexMessage>
                                 </requireProperty>